# Plantilla Laravel @foreach order by DESC

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, blade

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<div class="container">

        @if($boletines->isEmpty())
            <p class="text-center">{!! trans('website.no_hay_boletines') !!}</p>
        @else
            @foreach($boletines as $boletin)
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h1>{!! $boletin->titulo !!}</h1>
                        <iframe src="{!! $boletin->boletin !!}" style="border: none; overflow: hidden;" width="100%" height="400"></iframe>
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <a href="{!! $boletin->boletin !!}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin: 0">Ver Boletín</a>
                            @if($boletin->media()->where('sistema', \App\Database\Models\Media::SYS_NEWSLETTER)->first() != null)
                                <a href="{!! url('ver-archivo/' . $boletin->media()->where('sistema', \App\Database\Models\Media::SYS_NEWSLETTER)->first()->archivo) !!}" class="btn btn-primary">Descargar adjunto</a>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        @endif

    </div>
```

Lo que quiero es hacer que en el index los boletines se muestren de manera descendente, osea primero se visualice el ultimo publicado y al final el primero publicado.

Answer (score 0):

Al momento de hacer la consulta en el controlador (o donde sea que la hagas), agregas el método latest:

```
$boletines = Boletin::where('bla', 'foo')
                 ->latest()
                 ->get();
```

También podrías utilizar `->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')`, pero en este caso latest lo resume.

---

Una pequeña anotación, no es necesario usar un if y luego un foreach, cuando tienes forelse:

```
    @forelse($boletines as $boletin)
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1>{!! $boletin->titulo !!}</h1>
                <iframe src="{!! $boletin->boletin !!}" style="border: none; overflow: hidden;" width="100%" height="400"></iframe>
                <div class="text-center">
                    <a href="{!! $boletin->boletin !!}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin: 0">Ver Boletín</a>
                    @if($boletin->media()->where('sistema', \App\Database\Models\Media::SYS_NEWSLETTER)->first() != null)
                        <a href="{!! url('ver-archivo/' . $boletin->media()->where('sistema', \App\Database\Models\Media::SYS_NEWSLETTER)->first()->archivo) !!}" class="btn btn-primary">Descargar adjunto</a>
                    @endif
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @empty
        <p class="text-center">{!! trans('website.no_hay_boletines') !!}</p>
    @endforelse
```

Revisa su documentación en: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#loops